# Deeper nested transitions

Tags: python, pytransitions

I'm trying to use the hierarchical machine with three nesting levels called `main -> nested -> deeper`. I would expect, the state machines to be executed one after the other and then the states are remapped back to the first machine. So I would expect the final state is `done`, but it is `nested_deeper_working`, so obviously I'm missing something.

The workaround here is to use `queued=False`, then it works as expected. But the downside is the call stack is really long and the traceback in case of some error is long as hell.

Sorry for the long example I was not able to make it shorter. In real life I'm using the `MainMachine` as overall production control, it launches smaller machines to erase, flash, calibrate or test the device. These are represented by `NestedMachine`. Inside these machines are the smallest machines used eg. for hard-reset, one test sequence, or so. This is the `DeeperMachine` in this case.

```
pytransitions 0.8.10
python 3.7.3
```

`GenericMachine` class is just an abstract class. Here I define default states `initial` and `done` and also basic configuration.

```
from transitions.extensions import HierarchicalMachine

class GenericMachine(HierarchicalMachine):
    def __init__(self, states, transitions, model=None):
        generic_states = [
            {"name": "initial", "on_enter": self.entry_initial},
            {"name": "done", "on_enter": self.entry_done},
        ]
        states += generic_states
        super().__init__(
            states=states,
            transitions=transitions,
            model=model,
            send_event=True,
            queued=True,
        )

    def entry_initial(self, event_data):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def entry_done(self, event_data):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

`MainMachine` is the highest machine in the hierarchy and it launches the `NestedMachine`. It is expected that after all nested machines are done, the `done` state is executed.

```
class MainMachine(GenericMachine):
    def __init__(self):
        nested = NestedMachine()
        remap = {"done": "done"}
        states = [
            {"name": "nested", "children": nested, "remap": remap},
        ]
        transitions = [
            ["go", "initial", "nested"],
        ]
        super().__init__(states, transitions, model=self)

    def entry_done(self, event_data):
        print("job finished")
```

`NestedMachine` acts as the second level of nesting. It launches the `DeeperMachine` and remaps the `done` state.

```
class NestedMachine(GenericMachine):
    def __init__(self):
        deeper = DeeperMachine()
        remap = {"done": "done"}
        states = [
            {"name": "deeper", "children": deeper, "remap": remap},
        ]
        transitions = [
            ["go", "initial", "deeper"],
        ]
        super().__init__(states, transitions)

    def entry_initial(self, event_data):
        event_data.model.go()
```

The third level of nesting is implemented by `DeeperMachine`. After the work is done it triggers the `go` event to transit to the `done` state and jumps back through the `NestedMachine` to `MainMachine`

```
class DeeperMachine(GenericMachine):
    def __init__(self):
        states = [
            {"name": "working", "on_enter": self.entry_working},
        ]
        transitions = [
            ["go", "initial", "working"],
            ["go", "working", "done"],
        ]
        super().__init__(states, transitions, model=self)

    def entry_initial(self, event_data):
        event_data.model.go()

    def entry_working(self, event_data):
        event_data.model.go()
```

Test instantiates `MainMachine` and triggers the first event. It is expected the nested machines will be called and after the job is done, it will be remapped through the `done` states, back to the `MainMachine`.

```
import logging as log

def main():
    log.basicConfig(level=log.DEBUG)
    log.getLogger("transitions").setLevel(log.INFO)

    machine = MainMachine()
    machine.go()

    assert machine.state == "done"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: so without the useless transition in `NestedMachine` it seems it's working, but if I introduce the initial state and it's on_entry callback, the problem is back again

Comment: ok, so I changed the example, there is added explicit "initial" state with on_enter callback and the example is a little bit condensed

Comment: I expect the problem is in remap when the "done" state and transitions are remapped in NestedMachine, but how to handle it ...

Comment: one another workaround is to use `event_data.model.to_done()` in `entry_working`

Comment: I updated the example with implicit "done" state, but no solution so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed as a bug

https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions/issues/554

Resolved in dev-0.9, example and production code works well for me.